# Angular 2 and .net core 2.0 - issue with automatic deployment on Azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, angular-cli, devops

I have simple .net core 2.0 app with angular 2. 
For hosting my app I use Azure Web Service, also my source code published on GitHub. And always when I do some changes on the **master** branch it's automatically deployment on Azure.

It's work fine when I doing changes on **C#** code, but when I do any changes on Angular 2 + TS codec then my code cannot be deployed successfully. And I don't know why!

I have caught every time the same error like 
(**can't find and move main.84325e8f477352023e49.bundle.js file because it doesn't exist**)

But when I go to Azure dashboard and click - redeploy again it's work fine.

I use Angular-CLI for building the Angular 2 app.
Also, I have changed my ***.csproj** file to the execute some Angular-CLI command before building .net core app.

```
  <Target Name="Build Angular" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Message Text="* * * * * * NPM * * * * * *" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Message Text="* * * * * * Building Angular App * * * * * *" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" />
  </Target>
```

**npm run build:** - it is default Angular-ClI command for build angular app with AOT process **ng build --prod**

I found many articles when people use **Visual Studio Team Services** and create a deployment process for it for Azure, but I can't use this. I need to use the only deployment from GitHub.

Also, deployment takes a very long time like 15-20 min. And it's strange because local it's much faster like 1-2 min.

Any idea, how to improve deployment process and fix this issue with automatic deployment from the **master** branch on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side.It works well.

I used net core 2.0 angular template in the visual studio.

[image]

Then I use git to deploy whole application to git and enable the continues deploy in azure web app.

At last I edit the ts file and push to the github.

The result as below:

Takes 521 seconds:

[image]

I don't change and codes in csporj. So I suggest you could try to use vs net core angular template to build your project.

Comment: It's ok, but default core 2.0 angular template in the visual studio use web pack and server-side rendering. In my case, I have use Angular-CLI and .net core like API for front end side.

Comment: If you want to improve the npm speed, I suggest you could try to add an  appsetting SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH with D:\local\repository. It will speed up the continue deploy. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://ppolyzos.com/2017/01/15/how-to-improve-continuous-deployment-speed-in-azure-app-service/).

Comment: It's really helping me, for now, I have 10 min of deployment but previously I have 15-17 min. But it's still very long process for easy web app :(

Answer (score 1):

I know that when you deploy from Visual Studio, the `Build` target is executed twice. So may be in your case, your target is executed twice too.

The error *"can't find and move file"* may be related to the same reason. During publishing, the Publish task enumerates all the available files at the very beginning. Than it calls the second Build which wipes out the files from the first Build.

I recommend you to look at the following linked example of a target [`<Target Name="NgBuildAndAddToPublishOutput" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">`](https://github.com/andfomin/NgProjectTemplate/blob/master/AfominDotCom.AspNetCore.AngularCLI/build/AfominDotCom.AspNetCore.AngularCLI.targets#L52).